# SSRS chart report with sliders to filter or change dataset

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, charts, ssrs-2008, ms-access-2007

I have excel sheet with monthly sales/cost data. Every month I use excel to generate all sort of graphs and then publish them as a pdf. But I want others to be able to play around with the different data they have on the graphs. I want to publish reports on webpage which generate charts based on a table when it loads up.Then, I want the users to be able to use buttons or sliders to change the range of the dataset (mostly having dates or quaters or product type etc) and then the charts to update with the new results.

Also, can anyone help me find the equivalent of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128%28SQL.90%29.aspx) doc for sql 2008? I am looking for charts like [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa964128.moressrschartsfig10%28l=en-US,v=sql.90%29.gif)

I did some reading and found that SSRS can create all the charts that Excel can do. But I don't know if it can do all the calculations as well?
I also read we can make pivot tables in sql but am not sure if they are the same as the ones in excel where we can use them to filter data and the graphs show the changes real time.
I also read about MS Chart Control using ASP.net but I don't know asp and I don't know how much would researching about it help me in my case. 
I just want my visitors to be able to manipulate the dataset that is generating them graphs on their visit. Thats it. Dont' want to store their changes or anything.

What do you guys recommend? 
btw I have sql 2008 in mind to do this.
Do you guys recommend me to use Access 2007

Comment: Through `CUBE` drilling down, you can add a calculated measure to `SSAS` to work out the calculations you need for Chart's data.

Answer (score 1):

Do they need to view the report on a webpage or could it open in Excel (or the Excel IE browser plugin)?  [SoftArtisans OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-for-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx) has the ability to design rich Excel reports for SSRS with a template-based approach.  The output will be a true Excel file with live charts, formulas and pivot tables that can be manipulated by the user.  The out-of-the-box Excel export functionality doesn't have real formulas and charts.

Disclaimer: I work for SoftArtisans

Answer (score 0):

Excel Charts and ability to dynamically customize is a pretty advanced feature compared what is provided in SSRS... Matrix is the equivalent of pivot in SSRS. You can follow this MSDN article to get an idea of [Tables, Matrices, and Lists (Report Builder and SSRS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220592.aspx). This can be helpful in terms of [Reproduce an Excel Pivot table in SSRS 2008](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/f3a9cdcb-73f4-47b2-93ff-7e237dc57f1a)

[Here is a better tutorial if you could take a look.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/293855/Adding-Chart-Controls-to-SSRS-Report).
The most important aspect would be:-

- Set Datasource to Chart Control
- Define Fields to be used by Chart Control

> [Using **parameters** would be the best catch on filtering datasets. So you will need to have a secondary dataset on top of the main dataset.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155917.aspx)

- [How to filter one dataset value with another dataset Table value in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856913/how-to-filter-one-dataset-value-with-another-dataset-table-value-in-ssrs).

References:

- [Can SSRS use pivot tables such like excel drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258346/can-ssrs-use-pivot-tables-such-like-excel-drag-and-drop)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/4b4664e2-415b-41d4-99e6-1421aa70e7ac

Comment: Thanks. This helps me understand graphs better.
But I want the user/viewer of the published report on the webpage to be able to play around with things like select that all datasets he wants to select on the Y Axis or does he want to have all the datas plotted together. More like filters.

Comment: I believe that's where the `parameters` coming in. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155917.aspx

Comment: To be precise you can have another dataset on top of the main dataset, which is set to take in the parameters. So the results of the second dataset is the filtered source for your charts. In that case other users who are using the main dataset is kept intact. However the filtered dataset is localized to this user who is viewing the chart and changing it accordingly.